# JQuery's .prop() won't set a property

Tags: jquery, prop

I'm trying to use the JQuery `.prop()` function to add a custom attribute to an element, but to no avail. Here's what I've tried:

```
var header = $(document.getElementById("header-main"));
if (header.prop('error')) {
  //do something
}
else {
  $('#header-main').prop('error', true);
  header.prop('error', true);
  //neither of these change the element
  header.html('Changes some text'); //.html() actually seems to work.
}
```

I'm quite puzzled since I read the documentation and some posts on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to figure out the issue.

I'm using JQuery version 3.3.1 for what it's worth

Comment: use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attribute instead to add custom values. Properties are defined by the html standard of the respective element

Comment: also, developer-defined attributes should have the "data-" prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've answered your question in the first line.

> I'm trying to use the ***prop()*** function to add a custom ***attribute***

`prop()` sets *properties* and there's no such thing as a '*custom property*'. If you want to create a custom *attribute* use `attr()` - however I'd advise against that as it's bad practice.

A much better idea would be to store custom information in a `data` attribute instead. In other words, use `data()`

```
var $header = $('#header-main');
if ($header.data('error')) {
  // do something
}  else {
  $header.data('error', true).html('Changes some text');
}
```

> Can I still incorporate this without css? Right now I'm using css rules such as `#header-main[error]`

One thing to note here is that jQuery's `data()` method does not affect the DOM at all. As you require DOM updates, so that your CSS attribute selector will work, use `attr('data-error')` instead:

```
var $header = $('#header-main');
if ($header.attr('data-error') == 'true') { // ugly comparison, but not much we can do about it
  // do something
}  else {
  $header.attr('data-error', 'true').html('Changes some text');
}
```

```css
#header-main[data-error] { 
  color: #C00;
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Can I still incorporate this without css? Right now I'm using css rules such as `#header-main[error]`

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll need to use `attr()`. I'll update the answer to show you how

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in this case, adding a custom attribute is not bad practice since I'm making CSS rules? Still learning right now, so I'd Ike to do it right.

Comment: Adding a custom attribute is bad, but adding a custom `data-*` attribute is not. Think of the latter as a 'namespaced' custom attribute, if you like.

Comment: I understand. Thank you Rory :)